# How can I return file values in Jenkins choice parameter dropdown list?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have this `output.txt` file:

```
cg-123456
cg-456789
cg-987654
cg-087431
```

Is it possible to get these values into a jenkins dropdown, like by using `choice-parameter` or `active-choice-reactive` parameter?

Comment: Writing normal sentence in all upper-case is considered shouting. And it's rude to shout at the people you want to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the below.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Get Inputs") {
        steps {
         script{
          script {
            def input = input message: 'Please select the choice', ok: 'Ok',
                                        parameters: [
                                        choice(name: 'CHOICE', choices: getChoices(), description: 'Please select')]
          }
          
        }
        }
      }
  }
}

def getChoices() {
    filePath = "/path/to/file/output.txt"

    def choices = []
    def content = readFile(file: filePath)
    for(def line : content.split('\n')) {
        if(!line.allWhitespace){
            choices.add(line.trim())
        }
    }
    return choices
}
```

Comment: it is working but if i want to pass this  choice parameter (which i selected) in other command what should i use.  i  have used  $choice  $choices $CHOICE but its not working. can you please suggest what to use @ycr